# Spectral representation of a matrix

Tags: spectral-theory

I am given an operator $T: \mathbb{C}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3$ that is represented by the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now I am supposed to find the spectral family and the resulting spectral representation of $T$. We learned how to construct the spectral family by defining
$$
T_{\lambda} = T -\lambda I
$$
for a fixed $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. We then define
$$
T_{\lambda}^+ = \frac{1}{2}(B_{\lambda} + T_{\lambda}) ~~~~~~~\text{with }B_{\lambda} := (T_{\lambda}^2)^{1/2}
$$
Finally we define $E_{\lambda}$ as the projection of $H$ onto $\ker T_{\lambda}^+$.

Now in this specific case I calculated $T_{\lambda}$ to be
$$
T_{\lambda} = \begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -\lambda & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 - \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The square of this matrix is
$$
T_{\lambda}^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda^2 + 1 & -2\lambda & 0 \\
-2\lambda & \lambda^2 + 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & (1 - \lambda)^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So therefore
$$
B_{\lambda} = 2(\lambda - 1) I
$$
And finally
$$
T_{\lambda}^+ = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda - 2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & \lambda - 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda - 1
\end{pmatrix} ~~~~~~~~~\text{with } a_{\lambda} = 2(\lambda - 1) - \lambda
$$
Now to me it seems like $\ker T_{\lambda}^+ = \{0\}$ (with $0$ the null-element of $\mathbb{C}^3$).

My question is how do I get a spectral family from here? And how can I use the spectral theorem to get the spectral representation of this operator with this family?

Comment: I don't understand how you get $T_\lambda^2$ to have empty cells at $(1,2)$ and $(2, 1)$. I would have expected $-2\lambda$ in those cells.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I made a mistake there, I'll correct it, maybe I find the answer in the process

Comment: Okay I think this is now correct, the matrix looks a lot cleaner but I still don't know how to get the spectral family

Comment: Someone else will need to help you from here, I'm not up to speed on this area of maths.